# Connect a point geometry with a graphics label on a map

Tags: qgis, labeling, graphics

I am creating a map with traffic signals in a city.

Creating a point layer and adding my symbols as SVG mark is appropriate for 90%. But some signals explain alternativ routes used during events. These are not legible anymore when size is small enough to fit the map.

That's why I'd like to create a line between the point and the picture, similar as it is possible with labels. This would allow me to place these signals more outside and in a reasonable size.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use the Easy Custom Label plugin and and draw an empty label with an SVG background for this? So;

1. Give the difficult features their own layer.
2. Install the plugin and create an easy label layer with it
3. Make the label blank i.e. ' '
4. On background choose draw background , choose SVG and the appropriate SVG symbol (Note: I had to change the blending mode to make this work)
5. Move the label and the line is drawn automatically by the plugin

I tried this and got maybe 80% toward your solution. (But that was as i was working with dummy data)

Looks like:
[image: labels as image]

Comment: you're awesome! This is it! But I will use this instead of the easy custom label plugin: https://sigsemgrilhetas.wordpress.com/2015/01/12/etiquetas-com-guias-em-qgis-e-postgis-labels-leading-lines-with-qgis-and-postgis/ this will not create another label with is not connected to the database.